# using angular with pixi, rendering issues

Tags: angular, pixi.js

I'm using pixijs app, video playing in the background with a random number of small sprites over the video.

I'm getting artifacts from the random sprites, where they should pop on and pop off, but they pop on and don't really popoff.

I'm trying to host this in an angular app to provide the dependency injection and http gets. The pixi is hosted in an angular component that is the full screen.

I have a poc without angular and without the data feeds that appear correctly.

Is the angular host, the problem here?  How do I integrate with angular. I can do away with the visual part of angular.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about angular js but you can definitely use it in angular 6 and above. I have directly loaded pixi.js file from index.html using script src. Then load pixi js file from any component use declare var pixi:any.

To be on safe side you can also use angular zone.runOutSideOffAngular